# Migrating SVN to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, gradle, android-studio

I'm migrating my Android project from Eclipse to Android Studio. I use Subversion and am wondering how I can migrate my SVN to the new file structure used in Android Studio without losing my history.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the differences of both file structures. But it would try it this way:

1. Check out your project (maybe better use a client like TortoiseSVN)
2. Build the new file structure (new folders)
3. Commit
4. Move the files from the old structure to the new
5. Commit (check the commit dialog if there are move actions only!)
6. Delete old folders which you don't need anymore
7. Commit

SVN will recognize these move operations. You will see if it works by the operations in the commit dialog. If there are "delete"/"new" actions something went wrong there should only be "move" actions.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After further research, I think this is currently the best solution available. This means I won't be able to use the nice Android Studio import tool to automatically change the file structure and generate my gradle build file, but I can at least preserve my version control history.

Answer (score 8):

Posting this because it might help someone else.

I ran into the same problem as well. @user714965 was inspiring but didn't solve my problem because I couldn't figure out how to get SVN recognize that I moved a file from the original folder to the new structure in my working copy.

For the following, you will need TortoiseSVN or a similar SVN GUI client to do this.

Here is what I did:

1. Commit the Eclipse project last changes into the SVN repo.
2. Open Android Studio and use that to import the Eclipse project working copy.
3. Android Studio will nicely convert the Eclipse project into a Android Studio/Gradle project. Let's call this project "PrjGradle".
4. Open the converted Gradle project folder window and keep it one side of your screen
5. Go into your SVN repo where you have your project (using TortoiseSVN).
6. Backup your current trunk into a branch or a tag and call it "final_eclipse" or whatever.
7. Now, mirror the folder structure of the newly converted Gradle project on your local machine directly on the TortoiseSVN Repo Browser window. Meaning, look at how the directory is structured in "PrkGradle" and create/delete/rename folders directly on the trunk repository. This will be painstakingly tedious but you have to bear with it if you want to preserve your SVN history.
8. When you move files around (not copy) directly on the repo, the history of the files remain intact.
9. Once you complete, check out the restructured directory into your local machine. Let's call this "NewPrj".
10. Use a suitable Folder compare program (such as Beyond Compare) to synchronize missing items (such as build.gradle, .iml files, etc.)
11. Rename your converted project to "PrjGradle_old", and rename the newly checked out project (NewPrj) to "PrjGradle".
12. Open "PrjGradle" in Android Studio. That's it!

Hope it works out.

Comment: @Karim: Since I don't have permissions to modify the repository manually; so in step 7, is it possible to mirror the Gradle project (PrjGradle) structure (create/delete/rename folders) in the Eclipse project structure and then commit in SVN.

Comment: You could do that but you would probably have to gradually change the folder structure. Like delete one folder at a time in a folder tree and then commit. And then delete another one and then commit again. Then move a file and then commit again. Otherwise, you will get conflicting tree errors that you cannot resolve. Its going to be much more tedious than it already is. Maybe you can get temporary access to the SVN. Or have someone who has access to do it for you.

Comment: Using Android Studio import project feature saved a lot of work because it generated all the necessary gradle scripts.

Comment: Yes, the import feature works, but this tip is for those who want to keep their history of version control from Eclipse. If you restructure the Eclipse working folder into Gradle, your SVN will corrupt and you will relegate to starting over because it will be a nightmare to bring SVN up back again. Don't do this if you are starting a new Android Studio project, or if you don't care about your previous Eclipse SVN history.