# How to sync Studio Gradle project with SVN after Importing from Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, android-studio, eclipse-adt

I have an Android project stored in an SVN repository. This was created in Eclipse and does not use Gradle.

I recently switched to Android Studio and wanted to migrate to Gradle. I read this tutorial -
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

I followed the first step - Importing Directly into Android Studio.
This worked fine and the new Android Studio project migrated to Gradle successfully.

**But the new project in Android Studio is not linked to SVN any more.**

I tried this SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20356356/1371585
This just assumes that all my files are "Unversioned"

Is there any way for me to get the code (that doesn't use Gradle) from SVN into Android Studio and migrate the same project to Gradle without having to create a new repository?

I am using Eclipse IDE for Android Developers version 23.0.2.1259578 and Android Studio 1.2 Beta 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparently no direct way of doing this. When Android Studio imports a project from Eclipse ADT, it copies the files and creates a new project.

The new directory structure has to be created afresh in the SVN repository and the files have to be manually moved if their history has to be preserved.

I followed this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27387754/1371585