# How to migrate a APP checkout from Android code base to gradle project

Tags: android, git

It's very easy and convenient that use the "File"->"New"->"Import project" in Android Studio to migrate a APP originally built under Android code base using Android.mk to a gardle based project. However, when this APP use "File"->"New"->"Project from Version Control" to check out, it wouldn't generate any gradle related files that it can't be built within Android Studio. Is there a convenient way to check out codes from git and transfer it to gradle project at the same time? Or is there a way that can trigger import wizard to transfer project after check out codes from git?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Otherwise you always have option to separately clone and then import

Comment: Thanks! Sure it's. But since VCS is built in Android Studio, it seems more reasonable to do both checkout & import transfer at the same time.......
If there is really no such function currently, should I post a suggestion on Android Official forum?

Comment: Why not! And once you get some updates do answer on this post.

Answer (score 0):

please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248032/migrating-svn-to-android-studio/27387754#27387754)
 for migrating svn code to android studio project.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! And I am just curious is there a way that can can do both import & check out "at the same time"? Or if I can trigger "import project wizard" after I had checked out codes "within Android Studio"?