# Build.gradle Missing In Android Studio After Import From SVN

Tags: android, svn, gradle

I'm trying to convert over from Eclipse to Android Studio. I have all of my code checked into a SVN repository, and when I import the code into Android Studio, I don't have a build.gradle file. Is there a way to have Android Studio create one for me?

Comment: If you are migrating from Eclipse ADT then this article might help with any questions you have during the process. It should automatically create the Gradle-based build file during the import process. https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: Those were the steps that I followed. The difference was I imported from SVN instead of my Android project that I have stored locally.

Comment: Upon further inspection, it appears that the gradle file can't be generated for you. However if you ever come across any issues maintaining your SVN history you can see the following:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248032/migrating-svn-to-android-studio/27387754#27387754

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the help.